# HTTP Method OPTIONS JAX-RS

Tags: http, jax-rs, restful-authentication

My question is about HTTP OPTIONS Method with JAX-RS on Java.

I'm working on a API RESTfull of JWT authentication and I saw that it's better to create a method on my API for the HTTP OPTIONS method because the client with CORS, before the POST method, will request an OPTIONS method.

What should my OPTIONS method return ?